# Intersection of two lines and two planes

Tags: haskell, geometry

I am trying to implement intersection of two lines and intersection of two planes in Haskell without using Haskell library. How should I start doing it? Any template or implementation would be helpful for learning. I am a beginner in Haskell

Comment: You first work out a mathematical formula when two lines/planes intersect.

Comment: To expand on @WillemVanOnsem’s excellent point: once you have a formula, you can rewrite it as a Haskell function `linesIntersection :: Line -> Line -> Point` (or something along those lines). You can then call this function from the rest of your program.

Answer (score 2):

There are formulas for lines and planes in 3 dimensions.

## Line

[image]

If you have a v vector parallel with the L line (hopefully passing the O(0, 0, 0) point) and v = (a, b, c) and we also know of a P point on L where P = (x0, y0, z0) then:

**L <=> (x - x0) / a = (y - y0) / b = (z - z0) / c**

## Plane

[image]

If we want to define a Pl plane, then we need a point (x0, y0, z0) on the plane and a perpendicular vector to the plane, v = (a, b, c) to do so. The equation is now:

**Pl <=> a * x + b * y + c * z + d,**

where

**d = -(a * x0 + b * y0 + z * z0)**

## Haskell functions

Now that you know what the functions are, you only need to implement them:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/haskell/haskell_functions.htm

Using the information you have learned above you should be able to implement it.

## Intersections of lines and planes

The intersection of two metrical formulas is the set of points which fulfills both the equations. In case of lines the intersection is a point in most cases. If the two lines are the same, then their intersection is themselves.

The intersection of two planes is a line in most cases. It can also be a plane if we intersect a plane with itself.

You will need to program the evaluation of a system of equations, having two equations as input and an equation/point as output.

---

Illustrations were inspired from https://brilliant.org